# Internet recovery can't install macOS because it "requires downloading important content" which "can't be downloaded"

Tags: macos, macbook-pro

I used cmd-option-r to enter recovery mode and reset the MacBook Pro 2017 by reinstalling macOS before giving it to a friend to use.

Issue is, it now refuses to do anything. It won't install macOS as usual and it won't boot from a USB. I've tried formatting everything, resetting NVRAM, and setting the date/time. Is this thing actually bricked?

> Installation of macOS could not continue.
>
> Installation requires downloading important content. That content can't be downloaded at this time. Try again later.

[image: Disk Utility]

[image: Installation of macOS could not continue.]

Comment: Can you try the third option from this page (https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204904) and see if the recovery works.

Comment: Unfortunately that just does the same thing and brings up the internet recovery mode. Slightly panicked just now, only bought it a month ago

Comment: Are you sure it doesn’t boot from USB? What operating system (installer) does the USB have? Does it at least show up in the Boot Picker (press alt during boot to get to there)?